# Angular - Adding custom route at the end of all routes

Tags: javascript, angular, routes, angular-routing, angular-router

I want to have dynamic routing in my angular app. All my modules are lazy loaded. I resolved this problem with adding my route as child for all routes, but is little tricky. Maybe is the best way to do it, more Angular way.

Angular 7.2.0

```
const routes: Routes = [
    {
        path: '',
        loadChildren: './dashboard/dashboard.module#DashboardModule'
    }, {
        path: 'event',
        loadChildren: './event/event.module#EventModule'
    }, {
        path: 'account',
        loadChildren: './account/account.module#AccountModule'
    }, {
        path: 'settings',
        loadChildren: './settings/settings.module#SettingsModule'
    }
];
```

My goal is to have route, for example: '/create' which I could add at the end of all routes.

```
/create
/event/create
/account/main/create
```

Comment: You'll to have explicitely code it in each module. If you don't, you will need to use a function to do it for you : the issue is, decorators don't accept function calls (you can try, Angular will tell you). So no, there's no automatic way of doing that, as far as my knowledge of Angular goes.

Comment: Don't you have a sub router in each module ?

Comment: @An-droid Yes, Your're right I have sub routes, but I must add it for each child route in all my modules. I just wondering if it's more general solution, to add my '/create' route in main app module or somewhere else and not repeat it